# Admob Unity Banner Failed To Load 'Ad Failed To Load :0'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm currently making a game but I'm stuck on the AdMob part. Ad is not loaded on Request. AppID and AdUnitID I'm using is from Google's test unit. I've also tried my own too but returns the same error.

> Main Error : Not retrying to fetch app settings. Ad failed to load :
>   0.

I've tried AdMob Plugin 3.18.0 and 3.17.0. Both failed.

This is the logcat.

```
07-15 12:08:58.031 9847-9847/com.N1C3K.adtestplain D/AdsUnity: Calling loadAd() on Android
07-15 12:08:58.039 9847-9847/com.N1C3K.adtestplain D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
07-15 12:08:58.045 9847-9847/com.N1C3K.adtestplain I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
07-15 12:08:58.055 9847-11219/com.N1C3K.adtestplain I/AudioManager: In isSpeakerphoneOn(), calling application: com.N1C3K.adtestplain
07-15 12:08:58.059 9847-11219/com.N1C3K.adtestplain D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
07-15 12:08:58.061 9847-11219/com.N1C3K.adtestplain D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
07-15 12:08:58.089 9847-10176/com.N1C3K.adtestplain W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
07-15 12:08:58.262 9847-9847/com.N1C3K.adtestplain I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
07-15 12:08:58.274 9847-11248/com.N1C3K.adtestplain I/Unity: HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: Internal error
                                                             UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
                                                             UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
                                                             UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
                                                             UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
                                                             UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
                                                             AdManager:HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(Object, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs) (at C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\AdTestPlain\Assets\AdManager.cs:113)
                                                             GoogleMobileAds.Api.BannerView:<ConfigureBannerEvents>b__26_1(Object, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs) (at C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\AdTestPlain\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Api\BannerView.cs:127)
                                                             GoogleMobileAds.Android.BannerClient:onAdFailedToLoad(String) (at C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\AdTestPlain\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Platforms\Android\BannerClient.cs:136)
                                                             System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(Object, Object[], Exception&)
                                                             System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
                                                             System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[])
                                                             Unity
07-15 12:09:06.931 9847-9847/com.N1C3K.adtestplain V/MediaRouter: onRestoreRoute() : route=RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
07-15 12:09:06.932 9847-9847/com.N1C3K.adtestplain V/MediaRouter: Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
07-15 12:09:16.728 9847-9847/com.N1C3K.adtestplain V/MediaRouter: onRestoreRoute() : route=RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
07-15 12:09:16.730 9847-9847/com.N1C3K.adtestplain V/MediaRouter: Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
```

Comment: Are you testing with test ads first?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It happens in the following cases:

- Either your unit id is incorrect.
- If you have created Unit Ids just now, then wait for few hours as it take a while to be live.
- If you Ads were showing before but not now, then are you testing live Ads and clicking on live Ads from test device?, if yes then Admob might have detected it as spam and has blocked the unit id for your app.
- AdView is not provided with a required space to show load and show the Ad